# Can Swing components under SWT be accelerated?

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-rcp, awt

When using the SWT/AWT bridge to draw Swing components inside an SWT application, can these components benefit from AWT's hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running SWT_AWT does not change a way Swing components bahave. They will behave just as in standalone app.

Comment: Can you provide a reference for your proposition?

Comment: SWT uses JNI to talk to Java Swing. SWT is basically native widgets (win32/Cocoa/GTK) so Java behaves just the same way as if it was integrated into native app.

Comment: I accept this answer as correct - it sounds plausible. I can't verify it because we have switched to a SWT library.

Answer (score 0):

No, they cannot. Swing is being drawn by its own. And this is bad practice to mix AWT or SWT and Swing controls.

Comment: The fact that Swing draws its own controls doesn't prevent HW acceleration. Swing has been hardware-accelerated for quite some time now.